# Chrome extensions (and/or tampermonkey scripts) not running on certain websites (like gmail)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, tampermonkey

I have a very simple chrome extension that refuses to run on some sites like https://mail.google.com. It runs fine on other sites which makes me think something is limiting extensions/scripts from running on some sites. The sample case is quite simple and listed below.

With this sample case I see "Hello world" in the developer console when I navigate to https://about.me. I also see the extension in the Developer Console's Execution Context Selector. However, when I navigate to https://mail.google.com I don't see the log entry or the extension in the Execution Context Selector.

I have tried something similar with tampermonkey and am not seeing that script run on gmail either. Thanks!

**manifest.json**:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Gmail extension test",
  "version": "0.1.9",
  "description": "Try running inside gmail page",

  "content_scripts": [{
    "all_frames": true,
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "matches": [
      "https://mail.google.com/*",
      "https://about.me/*",
      "http://*/*",
      "https://*/*"
    ]
  }]
}
```

**content.js**:

```
console.warn("Hello world");
```

**Environment**:
Chrome 66.0.3359.117
macOS 10.13.3 (17D102)

Comment: Works fine for me, Chrome 66.0.3359.139, windows 10. ... On the toolbar, is the Tampermonkey icon grayed out?  If not, does it have a number showing?

Comment: If you're in a managed domain, your admin may have added gmail to a special list of sites that aren't visible to extension APIs.

Comment: Thanks Brock and wOxxOm. Knowing it wasn't just me helped me track it down (see Answer).

Answer (score 2):

As @wOxxOm suggested. I tracked down the problem to the fact that my company has a [Chrome policy](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187202?hl=en) set against running extensions on the google.com domain. I had no warning entries in the Developer Console or the macOS Console, I just tracked down other folks complaining about in an internal forum.

The policy that applies in this case is [ExtensionSettings](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionSettings) which is set in a OS/device specific way. To help diagnose this restriction, you can view your active polices in Chrome under `chrome://policy/`. In my case I had something like the following in my chrome://policy:

```
{
   "*": {
      ...
      "runtime_blocked_hosts": [ "*://*.google.com", ....]
   },
```

I'm not aware of a generic workaround for this at the extension level. Instead I had to work with my company IT department to whitelist the extension.