# TamperMonkey not running scripts only when loading youtube's homepage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey

I made a short script that makes that removes the 'play on tv' button on youtube, and the script itself works totally fine.

The problem is that the script doesn't even run at all when I start on youtube's homepage. And because of how youtube runs, when you click on a video, it continues to not run the script at all. But if I then refresh on the video page, the script starts running fine, even if I go back to the homepage then onto a video again(as long as it is the same tab). But then it will also stop working again if I refresh on the homepage. It also works totally fine when if I open a new tab on youtube directly onto a video. It just doesn't run when a new session of youtube is started on a tab specifically on the homepage.

I tried using these:

```
@match https://www.youtube.com/*
@include https://www.youtube.com
```

But the script still does not run at all.

I started to think this may be a bug on TamperMonkey's side because it isn't even only my script that seems to have this issue. I have one more script that runs on youtube, [Youtube Auto-Translate Canceler](https://github.com/pcouy/YoutubeAutotranslateCanceler/), that also seems to be running into this issue as well.

It is also bizzare that when you load onto the youtube homepage, TamperMonkey on the extension bar seems to show that there are 2 scripts running for a split second before it disappears and shows 'no scripts is running'.

As I was writing this, I tested these out:

```
@match https://*
@match https://*/*
```

And it still didn't work only for youtube's homepage.

I did see this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50070206/chrome-extensions-and-or-tampermonkey-scripts-not-running-on-certain-websites) that is maybe running into a similar situation, but I'm not too sure if this is the same problem, because to me it seems like if this is the case then it should not work for all of youtube, not just the homepage.

So I am now pretty convinced that this is a most likely a bug. But I do want to know if anyone knows any kind of work arounds if there are any. It may also have to do with google chrome specifically, but I'm not sure.

Thank you.

Comment: It might be a CORS issue.